# Linq group by one component, but do not lose info about others

Tags: c#, linq

I have a problem with LINQ statment, I have a list of colors, which is my class HSLCOLOR, where i keep info about Hue, Saturation, Lightness, and coordinates of pixel - x and y

```
public class HSLColor
{
    public double H;
    public double S;
    public double L;
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
```

I load an image, which have 425600 pixels, Im trying to count how many pixels doeas have the same lightness, - that's easy, but when i do that i loose all the other info about my pixel(H, S, x, y are no longer available)

```
 var q = (from x in colors
                 group x by x.L into g
                 let count = g.Count()
                 orderby count descending
                 select new { Value = g.Key, Count = count}).ToList();
```

So, what statment will be correct to do that? To have them sort by Lightness, but also, keep all the info about others components?

Comment: `select new { Value = g.Key, Count = count,Group=g}).ToList();` so you have a group containing all elements with that color in the list too. Then you can `SelectMany` them in order to flatten the buckets you grouped into if you want to resort later.

Comment: cool, ths it's working, but how can i access the H, S, and x, y?
q[0].Group?

Comment: Yes, or you can use SelectMany like my previous comment suggests. There is even an answer now showing you how.

Comment: sorry, one more problem, how to flat it?
Im doind sth with this list, reverse it, sort it, etc. etc. and now i need H, S, x and y to put pixels in the right order...

Comment: Flat what? Like we said SelectMany flattens a list of lists. (In query syntax that's repeating the `from` - no special function/keyword). Please elaborate

Answer (score 3):

Use `SelectMany` to extract the items from the groups:

```
 var q = (from x in colors
                 group x by x.L into g
                 let count = g.Count()
                 orderby count descending
                 select g)
         .SelectMany(g => g)
         .ToList();
```

Or as Servy points out you can do it all in query syntax:

```
 var q = (from x in colors
                 group x by x.L into g
                 let count = g.Count()
                 orderby count descending
                 from c in g
                 select c)
         .ToList();
```

Comment: You can keep it all in query syntax, instead of using method syntax for `SelectMany` and mixing/matching with query syntax.